Asymptotic Analysis of $ \epsilon^{2}\sqrt{a^{2}+\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}b^2}-\epsilon^{2}a$ as $ \epsilon \to 0 $
I want to analyze the asymptotic behavior of $\epsilon^{2}\sqrt{a^{2}+\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}b^{2}}-\epsilon^{2}a$ as $\epsilon \to 0 $, where $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be real numbers. My idea is to use Taylor expansion for a function $ f $. I will leverage the known Taylor expansion for functions of the form $ \sqrt{1+x} $. Thus, there are two approaches to consider:
$\textbf{1st Approach:}$
Let $ f(u) = \epsilon^{2}\sqrt{a^{2}+\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}b^{2}u} - \epsilon^{2}a $. We can rewrite this as:
$$
f(u) = \epsilon^{2}a\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}\epsilon^{2}}u} - 1\right).
$$
Using the Taylor expansion at $ u = 0 $ along with the Lagrange remainder, we obtain:
$$
f(u) = \epsilon^{2}a - \epsilon^{2}a + \epsilon^{2}a\frac{b^{2}}{2a^{2}\epsilon^{2}}u - \frac{1}{8}\epsilon^{2}a\left(1+\frac{b^{2}}{\epsilon^{2}a^{2}}\xi\right)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\left(\frac{b^{2}}{\epsilon^{2}a^{2}}u\right)^{2}=\frac{b^{2}}{2a}u+O(\epsilon).
$$
Consequently, using the Taylor expansion for $ f(1) $, we conclude that:
$$
f(1)=\epsilon^{2}\sqrt{a^{2}+\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}b^{2}}-\epsilon^{2}a \asymp \frac{b^{2}}{2a}.
$$
$\textbf{2nd Approach:}$
Let $ f(u) = \epsilon^{2}\sqrt{a^{2}u+\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}b^{2}} - \epsilon^{2}a $. We can rewrite this as:
$$
f(u) = \epsilon b \sqrt{\frac{a^{2}\epsilon^{2}}{b^{2}}u + 1} - \epsilon^{2}a.
$$
Applying the Taylor expansion at $ u = 0 $ with the Lagrange remainder gives us:
$$
f(u) = \epsilon b - \epsilon^{2} a + \epsilon b\frac{a^{2}\epsilon^{2}}{2b^{2}}u - \frac{1}{8}\epsilon b\left(\frac{a^{2}\epsilon^{2}}{b^{2}}\xi + 1\right)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\left(\frac{a^{2}\epsilon^{2}}{b^{2}}u\right)^{2}=\epsilon b + O(\epsilon^{2}).
$$
Thus, using the Taylor expansion for $ f(1) $, we find that:
$$
f(1)=\epsilon^{2}\sqrt{a^{2}+\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}b^{2}} - \epsilon^{2}a \asymp \epsilon b.
$$
However, these two approaches yield different asymptotic results, with the first yielding a constant term and the second suggesting a dependence on $\epsilon$. Given the discrepancies, I suspect that the latter approach is more accurate, as suggested by graphical analysis. This raises the question of where the error might lie in the first approach.
Any assistance in identifying the source of the discrepancy would be greatly appreciated.

It would help to know what $a$ and $b$ are allowed to be. Any real numbers?

$$\varepsilon ^2\sqrt{a^2+b\frac{1}{\varepsilon ^2}}-\varepsilon ^2a=\sqrt{\varepsilon ^4a^2+b\varepsilon ^2}-\varepsilon ^2a^2\to 0$$
when $\varepsilon \to 0$

The answer should involve nothing other than $\epsilon$, $a$, and $b$, and not this  strange $u$.

Yes @SineoftheTime. I have updated the question and corrected a lot of mistakes. I hope the question is now clear

$$\epsilon^{2}\sqrt{a^{2}+\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}b^2}=\epsilon^{2}\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon^{2}a^2+b^2}{\epsilon^{2}}}=\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{|\epsilon|}\sqrt{b^2+\epsilon^{2}a^2}=\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{|\epsilon|} |b| \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2\epsilon^2}{b^2}}$$
Now, since $\frac{a^2\epsilon^2}{b^2}$ goes to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, you can apply the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+t}$.

This would lead to the 2nd approach. But the question remains how the two different results from the different approaches make sense, or rather where the mistake lies

@randomwalker the real question is why are you introducing $f(u)$. It's more reasonable to consider $f(\epsilon)$. In the first method, note that $\epsilon$ is not fixed, so you cannot use the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{a^2 \epsilon}u}$ since if $\epsilon \to 0$, it's not automatic that $\frac{b^2}{a^2 \epsilon}u$ goes to $0$

I see your point. It makes more sense to look at $f(\epsilon)$. However, I still don’t see how $\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}\epsilon}u$ not going to $0$ affects the accuracy of the Taylor expansion, as the remainder seems to be of order $O(\epsilon)$. Hope you can help me once more

@randomwalker If also $\epsilon$ varies, then $f$ is a function of $u$ and $\epsilon$. The point is: it does not make sense to use the Taylor approximation if $\epsilon$ is not fixed
